# Optimal settings for Cloth dynamic to create jiggle

Tags: cloth-simulation

I followed a tutorial in an old version of Blender to create a jiggle effect for an object. Unfortunately the older version didn't have the same settings so it was hard to figure it out. Here's the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=boGA0Tn8-yY

Does anybody know the best settings for this type of thing? I've got pinning working using weights but any setting I use totally deforms the rest of the body. I could use some tips on this!

I'm a brand new Blender user, but with past experience in other packages. I've been learning this system (and loving it) over the pandemic.